# Como animar una transicion de colores en flutter?

Tags: flutter, animación

Estoy tratando de animar el color de un contenedor utilizando un AnimatedBuilder, sin embargo no se ve nada, a pesar de que mi codigo es similar al que se muestra en un ejemplo en línea:

> https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/animations/staggered-animations

Pueden probar mi codigo copiando y pegando en este enlace:

> https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/animation/animated-container

No estoy seguro si tengo que utilizar SingleTickerProviderStateMixin o simplemente TickerProviderStateMixin

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const AnimatedContainerApp());

class AnimatedContainerApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnimatedContainerApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AnimatedContainerAppState createState() => _AnimatedContainerAppState();
}

class _AnimatedContainerAppState extends State<AnimatedContainerApp>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> _playAnimation() async {
    try {
      await controller.forward().orCancel;
      await controller.reverse().orCancel;
    } on TickerCanceled {
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('AnimatedContainer Demo'),
        ),
        body: Center(child: Stagger(controller: controller)),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _playAnimation();
          },
          child: const Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Stagger extends StatelessWidget {
  final AnimationController controller;
  final Animation<Color> color;

  Stagger({Key? key, required this.controller})
      : color = Tween<Color>(begin: Colors.black, end: Colors.amber)
            .animate(CurvedAnimation(
                parent: controller,
                curve: const Interval(
                  0.0,
                  0.9,
                  curve: Curves.ease,
                ),),),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(animation: controller, builder: (context, child){
      return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color:color.value),
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La mayoría de tutoriales ahora están desfasados, en lugar de usar el `Tween<Color>` se debe usar `ColorTween`, quedaría así:

```dart
class Stagger extends StatelessWidget {
  final AnimationController controller;
  final Animation<Color?> color;

  Stagger({Key? key, required this.controller})
      : color = ColorTween(begin: Colors.black, end: Colors.red).animate(
          CurvedAnimation(
            parent: controller,
            curve: const Interval(
              0.0,
              0.9,
              curve: Curves.ease,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        super(key: key);
```

Recuerda que el `Color` dentro del `Animation` es opcional: `Animation<Color?>`

Comment: Gracias de nuevo :D me animé a seguir programando

Comment: @OmTav no te olvides de marcar la pregunta como resuelta :D